# Radio Button Group Swift 3 Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, radio-button, xcode8, radio-group

I have searched various sources and could not find a clear and simple solution for creating the equivalent of a radio button group in Swift 3 with Xcode 8.3 for an iOS application.

For example if I have 3 buttons in one group and only one should be selected at a time. Currently I am implementing this by changing the state of 2 buttons in the group to not selected when the other one is selected and vice versa.

```
@IBAction func buttonA(_ sender: Any) {
    buttonB.isChecked = false
    buttonC.isChecked = false
}

@IBAction func buttonB(_ sender: Any) {
    buttonA.isChecked = false
    buttonC.isChecked = false
}

@IBAction func buttonC(_ sender: Any) {
    buttonA.isChecked = false
    buttonB.isChecked = false
}
```

However I would expect a more efficient way to do this.

Any help on a more efficient solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Everything in your question is about macOS but you have tagged your question iOS. Which do you mean?

Comment: I see what you mean, I have in error mixed up the documentation. I do mean for iOS. To be clear I am struggling to find a simple way to create a radio button group for an iOS application.

Comment: There are no native radio buttons (or a radio group) in iOS. And you should update your question with relevant information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect all your button's `IBAction` to one single method.

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UISwitch) { // you're using UISwitch I believe?

}
```

You should add all the buttons into an array:

```
// at class level
var buttons: [UISwitch]!

// in viewDidLoad
buttons = [buttonA, buttonB, buttonC]
```

Then, write the `buttonClick` method like this:

```
buttons.forEach { $0.isChecked = false } // uncheck everything
sender.isChecked = true // check the button that is clicked on
```

Alternatives:

Try using a `UITableView`. Each row contains one option. When a row is selected, change that row's `accessoryType` to `.checkMark` and every other row's to `.none`.

If you are too lazy, try searching on `cocoapods.org` and see what other people have made.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my original question to be clear that I am referring to iOS. Indeed I have mixed up the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Just make a single selector for all three button's touchUpInside event, and set radio_off image for normal state and radio_on image for selected state in your IB, then only you have to connect btnClicked method to all button's touchUpInside event

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btnFirst:UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var btnSecond:UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var btnThird:UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func btnClicked(sender:UIButton){

    let buttonArray = [btnFirst,btnSecond,btnThird]

    buttonArray.forEach{

        $0?.isSelected = false

    }

    sender.isSelected = true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your UI, you could take multiple approaches.

**UITableView** - Use a `UITableView` with a checkmark decorator.  If your layout for these radio buttons is fairly traditional, this is the correct paradigm.  If the layout is a grid instead of a list, you could use `UICollectionView`.

You can use the `func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int)` in `UITableViewDelegate` to capture the selection.  You can call `indexPathForSelectedRow` on the tableView when you want to commit the change to determine which cell was selected.

Apple's tutorial on UITableView can be found at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html

---

**Manage a group of UIButtons** - You could store an array of references to UIButton objects that are part of your radio button group.

```
protocol RadioButtonDelegate: class {
    func didTapButton(_ button: UIButton)
}

class RadioButtonGroup {
    private var buttons: [UIButton] = []
    weak var delegate: RadioButtonDelegate?

    var selectedButton: UIButton? { return buttons.filter { $0.isSelected }.first }

    func addButton(_ button: UIButton) {
        buttons.append(button)
    }

    @objc private func didTapButton(_ button: UIButton) {
        button.isSelected = true

        deselectButtonsOtherThan(button)

        delegate?.didTapButton(button)
    }

    private func deselectButtonsOtherThan(_ selectedButton: UIButton) {
        for button in buttons where button != selectedButton {
            button.isSelected = false
        }
    }
}

class MyView: UIView {
    private var radioButtonGroup = RadioButtonGroup()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let button1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button1.setTitle("Eeeny", for: .normal)
        let button2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button2.setTitle("Meeny", for: .normal)
        let button3 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button3.setTitle("Miny", for: .normal)

        self.radioButtonGroup.addButton(button1)
        self.radioButtonGroup.addButton(button2)
        self.radioButtonGroup.addButton(button3)

        addSubview(button1)
        addSubview(button2)
        addSubview(button3)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but forgot add to:         button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var maleLB: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var femaleLB: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var otherLB: UIButton!

var gender = "Male"
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if gender == "Male"{
        femaleLB.isSelected = true
    }
}

@IBAction func maleBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
        femaleLB.isSelected = false
        otherLB.isSelected = false
    }
    else{
        sender.isSelected = true
        femaleLB.isSelected = false
        otherLB.isSelected = false
        
    }
}
@IBAction func femaleBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
        maleLB.isSelected = false
        otherLB.isSelected = false
    }
    else{
        sender.isSelected = true
        maleLB.isSelected = false
        otherLB.isSelected = false
        
    }
}
@IBAction func otherBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
        maleLB.isSelected = false
        femaleLB.isSelected = false
    }
    else{
        sender.isSelected = true
        maleLB.isSelected = false
        femaleLB.isSelected = false
        
    }

}
```

}